# Better way to identify cellphone numbers based on the first four digits

Tags: python

Currently I have this python program for identifying cellphone numbers based on the first four digits.

```
cellnum = (input("Enter your 11-digit cellphone number with no spaces or dashes: "))
n1 = cellnum[:4]
if n1 == "0917" or n1 == "0916":
  print(cellnum, "is Globe")
elif n1 == "0935":
  print(cellnum, "is TM")
elif n1 == "0918" or n1 == "0910":
  print(cellnum, "is Smart")
elif n1 == "0922" or n1 == "0923":
  print(cellnum, "is Sun")
else:
  print("~unknown provider~ :(")
```

Is there a better way to improve my script and make it more dynamic.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Are you asking about how to improve it? or if there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking on how to improve it ived made a simple example for you.

https://repl.it/@marksman/riavillacorte

```
cellnum = (input("Enter your 11-digit cellphone number with no spaces or dashes: "))

def checkProvider(numb):
    provider_key = numb[:4]
    providers = [
        ('Globe', ['0917', '0916']),
        ('TM', ['0935']),
        ('Smart', ['0918', '0910']),
        ('Sun', ['0922', '0923'])
    ]
    for provider in providers:
        provider_name, numbers = provider
        if provider_key in numbers:
            return provider_name
    return None


cellProvider = checkProvider(cellnum)

if cellProvider is None:
    print('~unknown provider~ :(')
else:
    print(cellnum, 'is ' + cellProvider)
```

Comment: Please don't encourage low-quality or off-topic questions by providing speculative answers.